# how to dynamically setAttribute className in Vue's v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js

I am new in Vue.js. There is my question:
I try this:

```
 <li v-for="(msg,index) in system_message" :class="index">
```

in order to create different className like 0,1,2,3 for every li element.
but v-bind does not work in this way. class name remain empty.
how do I use setAttribute function in Vue?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are not accepted as classes names, you should concatenate the index with string like :

```html
 <li v-for="(msg,index) in system_message" :class="`item${index}`">
```

that gives your `item0, item1, item2 ...`

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute can not be a number, you need to concatenate it with a string. Check the code snippet below with the two examples:

```js
new Vue({
  render: h => h({
  data() {
    return {
      system_message: ["Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3"]
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <li v-for="(msg,index) in system_message" :class="index">{{msg}}</li>
      <li v-for="(msg,index) in system_message" :class="'class-'+index">{{msg}}</li>
    </div>
  `
}),
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```